# libgpg-error HAVE_CONFIG_H

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to compile libgpg-error on cygwin but don't seem to be able to get pass the following errors during the make

```
gen-posix-lock-obj.c:39:3: error: #error sizeof pthread_mutex_t is not known.
 # error sizeof pthread_mutex_t is not known.
   ^
gen-posix-lock-obj.c: In function ‘main’:
gen-posix-lock-obj.c:55:21: error: ‘SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (sizeof mtx != SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T)
                     ^
gen-posix-lock-obj.c:55:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
gen-posix-lock-obj.c:84:11: error: ‘HOST_TRIPLET_STRING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
           HOST_TRIPLET_STRING,
```

the errors are triggered because HAVE_CONFIG_H doesn't seem to be set. I would imagine this would happen during the configure process, but i guess not. Any idea where to look at? I'm not that familiar with the whole automake stuff and some pointers on where to get started or a solution would be great

Comment: Why not use the libgpg-error package that's available from Cygwin's setup?

Comment: i'm trying to compile a library that needs a newer version of libgpg-error.

Comment: Ah. Well, I would start by getting the source for the current version that's available from Cygwin. From that you'll be able to see the configure flags and any patches that were used to create it. You should be able to use that as a starting point for compiling the newer version.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great idea. Will look into that.